# Switch statement in Groovy with XML/SAX

Tags: xml, groovy, switch-statement, sax

I managed to fix this issue, but it still puzzles me, so asking here.

I had some XML/SAX processing code inside a closure - always a nightmare to debug because the closure fails silently.

It was processing some lackeyml - (slightly out of date) DTD is here: https://github.com/mcmenaminadrian/lackey_xml/blob/master/lackeyml.dtd

I have a switch statement:

```
    void startElement(String ns, String localName, String qName,
    Attributes attrs) {
    switch (qName) {





        case 'instruction':
          [some code]
          break


        case 'store':
        case 'load':
        case 'modify':
          [some code]
          break

    default:
        println "Unrecognised element of type $qname"
    }
}
```

But this failed silently every time. But if I add:

```
        case 'lackeyml':
        break

        case 'application':
        break

        case 'thread':
        break
```

It works. What had I got wrong?

Comment: What does "fail silently" mean here?  Also if you change the case conditions and leave out the `[some code]` and it works, then maybe the original code there is just wrong?

Comment: Fail silently means that a 'bad' closure does not return an error message, it just doesn't run and so it's a nightmare to debug. The point about the other code was that it runs fine if I add the extra cases, so there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it as such - it's just the question of the missing 'cases' - but surely the default: case should pick them up anyway?

Comment: println returns null (it's a void function).  it can at best print that error there.  yet if something bends stdout, you will not see the error (can i assume this is not plain groovy, but something like jenkins?).  If you want a proper error, return a proper error or throw an exception.

Comment: No this is plain groovy, the println was simply to show progress through the XML, I'm not really bothered by what it traps